# How can OCRed text be preserved while converting between djvu and pdf files?

Tags: pdf, djvu

Suppose a pdf file has OCRed text. How can we convert it to a djvu file and pass the OCRed text to the djvu file?

Conversely, if exchange "pdf" and "djvu" in the above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For pdf to djvu, use [`pdf2djvu`](https://github.com/jwilk/pdf2djvu). Just tested. It keeps OCR layer.
In other way around, I have not tested anything but according to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/861292/how-can-i-convert-a-djvu-to-a-pdf-preserving-word-searchability) superuser post, [this](https://github.com/vindvaki/djvu2pdf) may work.

Comment: pdf2djvu by Jakub Wilk is great. Minor correction: it is spelled as here, without 'e' at the end. Can you edit your answer?

Comment: @Maxim Thanks. Done.